# Calculate the value of coshx using tailor series in cpp

Tags: c++, function, math, physics, factorial

I was assigned a task to calculate the value of coshx using tailor series in CPP.
I tried a simple approach by using factorial and power function, but i noticed that at larger values of x the factorial behaves abruptly and gives very deviating values
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
long double fact(int);
int main()
{
    long double a;
    long double sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter value of x " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    for (long c = 2; c <= 12; c++)
    {
        if (c % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (pow(a, c) / fact(c));
            if (sum < 0)
            {
                sum=sum*-1;
            }
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    cout << "The answer is " << 1 + sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
long double fact(int x)
{
    int n = 1, fact;
    for (n; n <= x; n++)
    {
        if (n == 1)
    {
            fact = 1;
    }
        else
    {
            fact = fact * n;
    }
}
    return fact;
}
```

even I have used long double to get maximum bits but that changes nothing and it just works well for fewer values(under 10) and less number of loops.

Comment: The `fact` function is suboptimal. You should do the test `if (n == 1)` before the `for` loop and not inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Because noone explicitly said it yet: You get overflow in calculating your factorial. Computers can only represent finitely large numbers, and `int` commonly only goes up to `2^31 - 1 = 2147483647`, which is smaller than `13! = 6227020800`. What happens when you go beyond that is technically **undefined behavior**, in practice you will likely wrap around and get more or less random integers.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment you get wrong results because of overflow. The factorial is particularly suspectible to overflow because it grows extremely fast. The thing is, sloppy speaking, this extreme growth is what makes the taylor series converge. If you consider the full term that you add on each iteration, it actually goes to `0`, instead of growing towards infinity (factorial is the denominator).

Instead of calculating the powers of `x` and the factorial individually you should just keep updating the the full term, ie instead of

```
sum = sum + (pow(a, c) / fact(c));
             //  ^ this may grow very fast
             //           ^ this definitely grows extremely fast
```

you should do something along the line of

```
double add = x;
double factor = 1;
while (add > eps) {    // with some appropriate value for eps
   sum += add;
   add *= (x / factor);   // <-- this will nicely converge to 0 
   factor++;
}
```

as others pointed out, this is actually the taylor series for the exponential, but you need only some minor modifications to get the desired result (eg skip the odd ones).

Comment: Your code actually calculates 'exp'. You must omit odd terms and keep even terms. I would set the condition as "abs(add)>(sum*numeric_limits<decltype(sum)>::epsilon())"

Comment: @Red.Wave thanks for pointing that out. Feel free to fix it, i wont have time too soon

Comment: @MohammadHassaan `eps` is some small constant that controls your desired accuracy

Comment: @user463035818 The problem is I too can't edit it right now.